# Unexpected behaviour when my js cart is toggled open and when it's not

Tags: javascript

(The JSbin link not working for some reason). Please find a [link](https://%20https://jsbin.com/nugaxus/6/edit) to my JS Bin website to familiarise yourself with the appearance even though there is no actual functionality there. I have a button marked 'Items' that when clicked, toggles my cart open or close. When the cart is toggled open, everything works fine as designed for i.e on clicking `ADD`, the respective item is added to the cart with the total cost marked with `Total:` displayed accurately as desired, moreover, if an item has already been added to the cart and `ADD` is clicked, an alert is displayed stating that the item has already been added to the cart to prevent duplications. However, when it is not toggled open, on clicking `ADD` the respective item is added but the total cost is returned as `NaN` contrary to how it behaves when `ADD` is clicked while cart is toggled open. Furthermore, there's no regard for the measures put to prevent duplication since a singe item gets added to the cart as many times as `ADD` is clicked.
Below is my JS code, I think the main function of interest could be the one called `addToCartClicked(event)` . Could it be that I'm perhaps calling a method the wrong way? Or ordering things inappropriately? Please help.

```
 //Checking whether DOM element has been fully loaded, if not i.e false, `if statement` is 
 //ran, otherwise the `else statement` is ran
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',ready);

}else{

    ready()
}

//enter engine function
function ready(data) {


// adding items to cart
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('item-addToCart')

    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {

        var button = addToCartButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click',addToCartClicked);
    }

//showing cart contents when cart button clicked
var cartInfo = document.getElementById('inCart');
var cart = document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0];

    cartInfo.addEventListener('click', function(){
        cart.classList.toggle('show-cart');
    })

var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-times-circle');

    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++ ) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
        // console.log(removeCartItemButtons.length)
    }

var add = document.getElementsByClassName('qty-inc')
        
    for (var i = 0; i < add.length; i++) {
        var addBtn = add[i];
        addBtn.addEventListener('click', addVal)
    }


var minus = document.getElementsByClassName('qty-dec')
        
    for (var i = 0; i < minus.length; i++) {
        var minusBtn = minus[i];
        minusBtn.addEventListener('click', minusVal)
    }   
    
    updateCartTotal()

}


//called when delete button in the cart is clicked; removing cart items
function removeCartItem(event){

    var buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();

    updateCartTotal()

}

//called when add button in the cart is clicked; for increasing quantity
function addVal(event) {
    
    var btn = event.target;

    var x = parseInt(btn.previousElementSibling.innerText)
        x = x+1;

    btn.previousElementSibling.innerText = x

    updateCartTotal()
        
}

//called when minus button in the cart is clicked; for reducing quantity
function minusVal(event) {
    
    var btn = event.target;

    var x = parseInt(btn.nextElementSibling.innerText)
        x = x-1;

    if(x<=0){

        btn.nextElementSibling.innerText = 1;

    }else{

        btn.nextElementSibling.innerText = x;
    }

    updateCartTotal()
    
}

//Called when add button is clicked, for adding items to cart
//?? I find it strange that each time ADD button is clicked, when the cart
//is not toggled open, the cart total comes back as 'is NaN' ontop of duplicating 
//items that already exist in the cart.
function addToCartClicked(event) {


    var button = event.target;

    var shopItem = button.parentElement;

    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText;
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText;
    var imgSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('item-image')[0].src;

    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title');

//I don't understand why this loop does not work when cart is not toggled open,
//it should prevent duplication of items in the cart by returning the alert function
//when an item is already in the cart yet it only works when the cart is open
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title ) {
            alert('Item already added to cart');
            return
        }

    }

    var cartRow = document.createElement('div');
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    
    

    var cartRowContents = `

                 <div class="cart-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            
                     <div class="cart-item-image"></div>
                    <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
                 </div>

                 <span class="cart-item-price">${price}</span>

                 <div class="cart-item-qty">
                   <i class="fa fa-minus qty-dec" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   <span class="item-quantity">1</span>
                   <i class="fa fa-plus qty-inc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 </div>                 
                                `
    
    
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
    cartItems.append(cartRow)

    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('fa-times-circle')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('qty-dec')[0].addEventListener('click', minusVal);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('qty-inc')[0].addEventListener('click', addVal);


updateCartTotal()
    
      // <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imgSrc}">
}

//this is where all calculations associated with the cart total cost 
//and number of items in the cart happen;
//including determinantion of the number of items in the cart. And whenever
//quanity is increased, decreased or an item removed or added to the cart,
//it is called to perform the calculations suitably.
function updateCartTotal() {

    var all = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    var tot = all.getElementsByClassName('cart-row');

    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < tot.length; i++) {

        var currentCartItem = tot[i];

        var priceElement = currentCartItem.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-price')[0];
        // console.log(priceElement)
        var quantityElement = currentCartItem.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-qty')[0];
        // console.log(quantityElement)
        var quantityEl = quantityElement.getElementsByClassName('item-quantity')[0];

        var price = parseInt(priceElement.innerText.replace('KES:',''));
        // console.log(price)

        var quantity = quantityEl.innerText;
        // console.log(quantity)

        total = total + (price * quantity);
        // console.log(total)

    }
        total = Math.round(total*100)/100;
        
        // console.log(total)
        document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = 'KES' + " " + total;
        document.getElementById('inCart').innerText = tot.length;

}
```

Comment: I only skimmed your code but it looks like trouble is brewing in several places. The most important aspect here is that it violates "separation of content and presentation"; your cart should exist as object/array in memory ("app state"/content). When a user interacts with your page, the app state changes; this change is subsequently reflected in the presentation, i.e. your HTML.  Also, relying on siblings and parents is bound to break at the earliest chance it gets; never do that. Use classes and `element.querySelector(selector)` to go down the tree, `element.closest(selector)` to go up.

Comment: Here's a React example app that demonstrates the basic idea: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7918ot5d/ (you don't need to learn React but using state and turning it into HTML is pretty much universal for JS apps)